# Python: How do I convert each character in a string to a list?

Tags: python, string, list

Say I have a string like this:

```
'0123456789'
```

can I convert that into a list like this?

```
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

Thanks in advance! *I've been searching for a while, but haven't found precisely what I want, so I asked a question.*

Comment: `list('0123456789')`

Comment: well that was simpler than i thought it would be :D

Comment: Dukeling I think your right

Comment: For many use-cases like iteration and indexing you can the string directly. It's a sequence type.

Answer (score 1):

```
print(list(s))
```

Output:

```
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.